# Solve a fractional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, absolute-value, fractions

How do you go from this step:

$$
\frac{a_2b_2}{\left(b_2+x\right)^2}-\frac{a_1b_1}{\left(b_1-x\right)^2} = 0
$$
To this step:

$$
(a_1b_1-a_2b_2)x^2 + 2b_1b_2(a_1+a_2)x + b_1b_2(a_1b_2 - a_2b_1) = 0 
$$

Have tried to do it but my maths are a bit rusty at the moment, It would be nice if somebody could do a step by step on how to get to that.

What I have tried:
$$
\frac{(a_2b_2(b_1-x)^2)-(a_1b_1(b_2+x)^2)}{\left(b_2+x)^2(b_1-x\right)^2} = 0
$$
multiply denominators and then cross-multiply numerator with denominator, unfortunately I do not know how to continue this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show your own efforts.

Comment: There are other ways to provide *context* besides showing your own efforts.  You could explain the source of the problem, why it is important to you, or what about clearing the fractions seems daunting to you.  Perhaps the key thing is to share with Readers what is challenging about the problem (so that Answers can be targetted to your level of understanding).

Comment: I added what I have tried, I want to know how to go from the first step to the last step, in the last step you can find the roots easily with the quadratic formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $(b_2+x)^2(b_1-x)^2\ne 0$ we have

$$
(b_2+x)^2(b_1-x)^2\left(\frac{a_2b_2}{\left(b_2+x\right)^2}-\frac{a_1b_1}{\left(b_1-x\right)^2}\right)=(b_1-x)^2a_2b_2-(b_2+x)^2a_1b_1=\\
(b_1^2-2b_1 x+x^2)a_2b_2-(b_2^2+2b_2 x+x^2)a_1b_1=0
$$

the last step is left.

Answer (score 1):

> What I have tried: $$
>  \frac{(a_2b_2(b_1-x)^2)-(a_1b_1(b_2+x)^2)}{\left(b_2+x)^2(b_1-x\right)^2}
>  = 0 $$

You are almost there. You have an equation of the form: $\frac{y}{z} = 0$. This implies $y=0$ i.e.

$$ a_2b_2(b_1-x)^2-a_1b_1(b_2+x)^2 =0.$$

Now expand and re-arrange this into the form

$$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0,$$

and you're done.

Answer (score -4):

$$
\frac{a_2b_2}{\left(b_2+x\right)^2}=\frac{a_1b_1}{\left(b_1-x\right)^2}
$$

Without loss of generality, assume both $a_1b_1$ and $a_2b_2$ are positive, then we take a square root on both sides

$$
\frac{\sqrt{a_2b_2}}{|b_2+x|}=\frac{\sqrt{a_1b_1}}{|b_1-x|}
$$

we get

$$
\sqrt{a_2b_2}\cdot(b_1-x)=\pm\sqrt{a_1b_1}\cdot(b_2+x)
$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: why downvote ?.